# WPF: message box with checkbox added

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net

In WPF I am looking for a "do not show again" checkbox on my messagebox popup.

Does anyone know where I can get such a control or maybe how to copy the style of the regular WPF messagebox so I can create my own?

Thanks

Comment: are you asking that your "custom message box" changes style whenever the system changes the style of the standared message box?

Comment: No, I want to get the style to look the very same as the WPF messagebox control, harcoding the style is fine. Is there any way of applying the style of a standard control to a custom control?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Dialog Boxes Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx).  The overview covers Message Boxes, Common Dialog Boxes, and Custom Dialog Boxes. In your case you'll want to create a simple Custom Dialog Box that includes a message, a checkbox, and however many buttons you need.

Basically you need to define a new code-behind file that includes your `TextBlock`, `CheckBox`, and `Button`s in a panel object, and you need to extend `Window`. In your code-behind file you implement any necessary logic to implement the user's choice, and you return this result to the object containing the custom dialog box.

Make sure to pay special attention to this line of code when creating your custom dialog box:

```
// Open the dialog box modally 
messageBox.ShowDialog();
```

The call to `ShowDialog()` will ensure that the user must take action against your dialog box before moving on to other parts of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think , you may have to create  by yourself  and it is really easy in the WPF

Comment: The time consuming thing is getting the style to look the very same as the WPF messagebox control. Is there any way of applying the style of a standard control to a custom control to save myself the time?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a dialog box. An easy way to do it would be to keep a variable in the project settings that would be updated on the popup close() event. So then you would just have to verify the value in the project settings before showing the popup.